# How many $n^{th}$ powers do I need to add to get a positive density of natural numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Given a natural number $n$, I do see that density of the set $S = \{x_{1}^{n} + x_{2}^{n} + ... + x_{n-1}^{n} : x_{1}, ... , x_{n-1} \in\mathbb{N} \}$ is clearly zero due to simple counting reasons.

This is because $d(S) \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} \frac{{n \choose 1} + { n \choose 2} + ... + {n \choose n-1}}{n^{n}} = 0 $ since the numerator is a polynomial of degree $n-1$.

My intuition says that the density of set $T = \{x_{1}^{n} + x_{2}^{n} + ... + x_{n-1}^{n}+x_{n}^{n} : x_{1}, ... , x_{n} \in\mathbb{N} \}$ should be positive. However, all I could show that $d(S) \leq \frac{1}{n!}$. Is my intuition correct that $d(T) > 0$?

I cannot seem to even show that the density (i.e. the limit in the definition) exists. I would be happy if I could show that $\overline{d}(T) = \limsup_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{|T \cap \{1, ... , k\} |}{k} > 0$.

Comment: Since $n$ (the exponent) is fixed, you want to use a different symbol, say $N$, for the limit. Also can you see what happens for $n=2$?

Comment: Ahh I see..  for $n = 2$, I suspect that the density is actually zero. May be I should say $n \geq 3$ in that case. Then my intuition might make more sense. Right?

Comment: I agree for $n=2$ the density is $\prod_{p=4k-1}(p/(p+1))=0$ because it can't have an odd power of any of those primes

Comment: For $n=2$, $N=3$ works  with density $5/6$ because the only ones missing are $4^k(8m+7)$

Comment: Relevant article on the density of sums of three cubes, and some weak results on the density $s$-fold sums of $s$-th powers: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11792086_11

Comment: @Servaes I do not have access to that book, it appears. I am still wondering how to prove/disprove my intuition.